# Joining two DataFrames from the same source

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am using the DataFrame API of pyspark (Apache Spark) and am running into the following problem:

When I join two DataFrames that originate from the same source DataFrame, the resulting DF will explode to a huge number of rows. A quick example:

I load a DataFrame with `n` rows from disk:

```
df = sql_context.parquetFile('data.parquet')
```

Then I create two DataFrames from that source.

```
df_one = df.select('col1', 'col2')
df_two = df.select('col1', 'col3')
```

Finally I want to (inner) join them back together:

```
df_joined = df_one.join(df_two, df_one['col1'] == df_two['col1'], 'inner')
```

The key in `col1` is unique. The resulting DataFrame should have `n` rows, however it does have `n*n` rows.

That does not happen, when I load `df_one` and `df_two` from disk directly. I am on Spark 1.3.0, but this also happens on the current 1.4.0 snapshot.

Can anyone explain why that happens?

Comment: Sorry are you wanting `df_one.merge(df_two, left_on='col1', right_on='col2', how='inner')`?

Comment: @EdChum Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using Apache Spark and edited the question to reflect that. There is no such thing as `merge` on a Spark DataFrame I'm afraid.

Comment: OK thought this might be a pandas question

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your use case, since splitting and then joining back together sounds a bit sub-optimal? Why the split?

Comment: @MarkoBonaci This is a contrived example. In reality one might want to do something complex with part of the data, do something else with another part of the data and then maybe implement a filter by inner joining the two results. There are always other means to achieve the same thing of course, but still the above should work, right?

Answer (score 4):

If I'm reading this correctly, df_two doesn't have a col2

```
    df_one = df.select('col1', 'col2')
    df_two = df.select('col1', 'col3')
```

So when you do:

```
    df_one.join(df_two, df_one['col1'] == df_two['col2'], 'inner')
```

That should fail. If you meant to say

```
    df_one.join(df_two, df_one['col1'] == df_two['col1'], 'inner')
```

However, the fact that you're loading from the same data frame should have no impact. I would suggest that you do:

```
    df_one.show()
    df_two.show()
```

To ensure that the data you've selected is what you expected.

Comment: I meant to say `df_one['col1'] == df_two['col1']` indeed. I've fixed that typo in the question.

Comment: In that case, do the following test:
df_joined.orderBy(['col1']).show(10)
If there are duplicate rows, then I'm not sure, i would think possibly due to you using an old version of spark. If each row is different, then col1 is not truly unique. From my attempts, using spark 1.5.2 this is not an issue and this join would not create multiple iterations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this problem in my large dataset too, on Spark 1.3. Unfortunately, in the small, contrived examples I made up 'join' works correctly. I feel like there's some underlying bug from the steps preceeding the join perhaps

Performing the join (Note: DateTime is just a string):

```
> join = df1.join(df2, df1.DateTime == df2.DateTime, "inner")
> join.count()

250000L
```

This is obviously returning the full 500*500 cartesian join.

What does work for me is switching to SQL:

```
  > sqlc.registerDataFrameAsTable(df1, "df1")
  > sqlc.registerDataFrameAsTable(df2, "df2")
  > join = sqlc.sql("select * from df1, df2 where df1.DateTime = df2.DateTime")
  > join.count()
  471L
```

That value looks right.

Seeing this, I personally will not be using pyspark's DataFrame.join() until I can understand this difference better.